# how to upgrade the GoogleAdmobAdSdk-6.4.1.jar?

Tags: android, jar, google-play-services

Hi i have used flurryAgent.jar for flurry admob , i just want to replace furry into google admob sdk but it says need to upgrade if still using  GoogleAdmobAdSdk-6.4.1.jar as from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android

so i need to upgrade google admob sdk to latest and want to replace flurry into google admob sdk i have updated my android sdk into latest version and imported google play service lib as reference for my native app to support google add mob sdk but still getting error as Jar mismatch for google-play-services_lib

Please tell me how to resolve this error and how to upgrade the GoogleAdmobAdSdk-6.4.1.jar into latest?

Answer (score 0):

As they where update instead of  GoogleAdmobAdSdk-6.4.1.jar now they were replaced withe Google play service.first of all try to update Google play service in the sdk manager under Extras folder and the difference from before to latest admob you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration) and the [Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play)

Comment: Hi vinay thanks for ur answer, i have update my android sdk and imported google play service lib folder and set the reference to my native and deleted old jar file of GoogleAdmobAdSdk-6.4.1 now i got error'My app name' is missing required library: 'libs/google-play-services.jar'Build Path Problem

Comment: ya, i have added, now i got  error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package 'com.google.ads'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package 
  'com.google.ads'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.ads'  and got error in com.myApp.android.R

Comment: try to follow this difference this site https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migrationyou can find it and try to import this package not that com.google.android.gms.ads.*

Comment: i got that error in my xml when i add this code <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize = "BANNER"        
                ads:adUnitId = ""
                ads:loadAdOnCreate = "true">
                
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>  and does not view when i type these attributes even added the google play service library

Comment: have you updated the google play services in sdk manger try to update only that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57417/discussion-between-siva-and-vinay-maneti).